# How to remove bottom space in a pie chart?

Tags: android, android-layout, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using Pie Chart in my application, Right now Pie Chart is displaying properly ,only issue is getting space at bottom of Pie Chart. Following is code of Pie Chart  and output what I want and What I am trying to get.

Using this library for piechart

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

```
 PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chart);
        pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated

        int offset = (int)(height * 0.65); /* percent to move */

       /* RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)pieChart.getLayoutParams();
        rlParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -offset);
        pieChart.setLayoutParams(rlParams);*/
        // IMPORTANT: In a PieChart, no values (Entry) should have the same
        // xIndex (even if from different DataSets), since no values can be
        // drawn above each other.
        ArrayList<PieEntry> yvalues = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
        yvalues.add(new PieEntry(8f, 0));
        yvalues.add(new PieEntry(15f, 1));
        yvalues.add(new PieEntry(12f, 2));


        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "Reward Points");

        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

        xVals.add("January");
        xVals.add("February");
        xVals.add("March");
        xVals.add("April");
        xVals.add("May");
        xVals.add("June");

        PieData data = new PieData( dataSet);

        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        pieChart.setData(data);
        //pieChart.setDescription("This is Pie Chart");

        pieChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(18f);
        pieChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        pieChart.isRotationEnabled();
        pieChart.isHighlightPerTapEnabled();
        pieChart.setCenterTextOffset(0f,-20f);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.WHITE);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(16f);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(11f);

        pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);


        pieChart.setMaxAngle(180.0f);
        pieChart.setRotationAngle(180.0f);
        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(30);

        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        data.setValueTextSize(13f);

        data.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        //pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(getActivity());

        pieChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);
```

Expected Output

[image: Out]

Getting Output

[image]

Comment: Do you required that 'Description Label' text? Basically what I understand is: you need to remove space between chart and text 'Reward Points' right?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya expected output ss is there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code.

```
pieChart.setHoleRadius(64f);//18f
pieChart.setCenterTextSize(10);//30
pieChart.setCenterText("Reward Points: 150");//new line

pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5f,0f,10f,-100f);
```

Adjust value of *bottom offset* in `setExtraOffsets`(in above code value -100f) in order to adjust space.[image]

Comment: yes it worked for me, needed little changes also, that i managed. but finally found solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

To get the expected output,

1. You need to add a negative bottom margin
       // Use LinearLayout.LayoutParams since you use a linear layout
       // set buttom margin (I used -450 change this as you need)

   ```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlParams =
           (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) pieChart.getLayoutParams();
   rlParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -450);
   pieChart.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
   ```
2. Disable the description

   ```
   pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false); // remove the description
   ```
3. Increase hole radius

   ```
   pieChart.setHoleRadius(50f);        // increase hole radius
   ```
4. Reduce center font size and set text

   ```
   pieChart.setCenterTextSize(15); // reduce font size
   pieChart.setCenterText("Rewarded points: 140"); // set center text
   ```

Also change the height to 400dp in your xml file.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/fragment_chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: I have recyclerview below my piechart. I tried as per your suggestion but still pie chart has same size, no change i am getting ..

Comment: I tried your layout and it works, I have updated the code. REMEMBER to add a negative margin (check my answer)

Comment: please check this.. this is what i am getting in my output https://imgur.com/a/qca7Zt7

Comment: have you tried changing the bottom margin? try something like -200 and check

Comment: What's the output you're getting now? Did u able to reduce the space?

Comment: space reduced little bit, but circle is still same and reward point text is completly messed up..

Comment: I updated the answer. Change the margin to -450 and change the height to 400dp in your XML file. Hope this will finally solve the issue!!

Comment: if i go with -450 pie chart not at all showing..only recyclerview is there